# Magento 2 - Pass data to checkout during runtime

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, knockoutjs, carrier

I created a new carrier method for express shipping. I need to show a dynamic message which I am generating based on the products in the cart. There are some product categories which are not allowed with the new carrier method.

So I need to show a message like:

> The following products are not compatible with the express shipping
> method:
>
> - Product x
> - Product Y ...

I am generating the message in the code where I am creating the carrier. But I don't know how to pass the generated message to the view.

**app/code/Company/Shipping/Model/Carrier/CompanyExpress.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class CompanyExpress extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier
              implements \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    ...
    
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel */
        $categoryModel = $this->_categoryFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart */
        $cart = $this->_cartFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();

        $rule = $this->_carrierHelper->getShippingRule(
                     $quote
                    ,$this->_productRepository
                    ,$categoryModel
                    ,$this->_scopeConfig
                );
        if ( ! $rule) { return false; }

    // Add Express Shipping Method
        $expressRule = $rule["rules"]["express"];

        if ($expressRule["active"]) {

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $carrierTitle = $expressRule["carrierTitle"];
            $methodTitle = $expressRule["methodTitle"];
            $shippingCost = $expressRule["shippingCost"];

// ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
// ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
// ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

            $note = $this->_generateNote($expressRule);     // <----- How can I pass this note to the view?

// ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
// ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
// ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($methodTitle);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($carrierTitle);
            $method->setPrice($shippingCost);
            $method->setCost($shippingCost);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }
    
    private function _generateNote($expressRule)
    {
        $block = $this->_notAllowedCategoriesBlockFactory->create();            
        $block->setExpressRule($expressRule);
        $html = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $block->toHtml());

        return $html;
    }
    
    ...
```

As you can see I am generating the Note with `_generateNote()` but I don't know how I can pass it to the view.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a different approach, why do you need to pass data from collectRates directly?

If you want to add a html message in the view later you can from a block use e.g.

```
\Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface::getList
```

And check for the express one and if it is not there generate and display the message?

Comment: Because the data I need to display is generated in this step. If I would do it like you say, then the same logic has to run twice which is not performant and I want a really fast checkout.